# What is the best way to make this code dry?

Tags: python

I have a script that makes a bunch of api calls (xml) and it's not adhering to DRY because I am repeating a lot of the code in the functions, what would be the best way to clean this up and reduce the amount of repeat code?

```
def get_api_key(hostname, username, password):
    url = 'https://' + hostname + '/api'
    values = {'type': 'keygen', 'user': username, 'password': password}
    response = requests.post(url, params=values, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
    return ET.fromstring(response.text).find('.//result/key').text

def add_template(hostname, api_key, template_name, name):
    url = 'https://' + hostname + '/api'
    values = {'type': 'config',
        'action': 'set',
        'xpath': f"entry[@name='{template_name}']/",
        'element': f"<tag>{name}</tag>",
        'key': api_key
        }
    requests.post(url, params=values, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
    return(template_name)

def add_template_stack(hostname, api_key, stack_name, template_name):
    url = 'https://' + hostname + '/api'
    values = {'type': 'config',
        'action': 'set',
        'xpath': f"entry[@name='{stack_name}']",
        'element': f"<tag>{template_name}</tag>",
        'key': api_key
        }
    requests.post(url, params=values, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
    return(stack_name)

def add_variable(template_name, var_name, netmask, hostname, api_key): 
    url = 'https://' + hostname + '/api'
    values = {'type': 'config',
        'action': 'set',
        'xpath': f"entry[@name='{template_name}']/variable/entry[@name='{var_name}']",
        'element': f"<tag>{netmask}</tag>",
        'key': api_key
        }
    requests.post(url, params=values, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
    return(var_name)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but `return` shouldn't have parenthesis after it. Just `return x`.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good way to reduce the WET code here is to consolidate and generalize the core functionality to a single function, and tweak the arguments going into it accordingly. I left the `get_api_key` function alone and focused on the other ones as they are the most similar. See below:

```py
def add_template_2(hostname, api_key, template_name, name):
    return add(hostname, api_key, template_name, name)


def add_template_stack_2(hostname, api_key, stack_name, template_name):
    return add(hostname, api_key, stack_name, template_name)


def add_variable_2(template_name, var_name, netmask, hostname, api_key):
    return add(hostname, api_key, template_name, netmask, var_name)


def add(hostname, api_key, xpath_name, element, xpath_var=None):
    url = f'https://{hostname}/api'

    if xpath_var:
        xpath = f"entry[@name='{xpath_name}']/variable/entry[@name='{xpath_var}']"
        ret_val = xpath_var
    else:
        xpath = f"entry[@name='{xpath_name}']"
        ret_val = xpath_name

    values = {'type': 'config',
        'action': 'set',
        'xpath': xpath,
        'element': f"<tag>{element}</tag>",
        'key': api_key
        }
    requests.post(url, params=values, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
    return(ret_val)
```